# Java Regex Suffix

Tags: java, regex

I am currently working with java regexes attempting to match a username with the following conditions:

1. Must start with letter (upper or lower case)
2. Must be no more than 8 chars in length
3. May have digits, but they must be at the end (so sjh23 would match but not sj23h)

I know to start with ^[A-Za-z] and the length can be managed with {0,7} but I don't know how to make it so any digits would be a suffix.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you just check the length with `String.length()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check length of string with regex you can use [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism and add `(?=^.{1,8}$)` at start of regex.

So your regex can look like

```
(?=^.{1,8}$)[A-Za-z]+\\d*
```

Also you can do it with `length()` method like

```
if(yourString.matches("[A-Za-z]+\\d*")  &&  yourString.length()<=8){//...
//you dont need to check if yourString.length()>=1 since [A-Za-z]+ makes string
//to contain at least one character
```